# Swap keys for values in dictionary?

Tags: swift

I have an dictionary in Swift that looks like this:

```
[
    0: "82",
    1: "12",
    2: "3",
    3: "42"
    // Etc.
]
```

And let's say I want to swap the keys for values 82 and 3, so the new dictionary looks like this:

```
[
    0: "3",
    1: "12",
    2: "82",
    3: "42"
    // Etc.
]
```

How would I do this? (I have found no tips and have no idea how to go about doing this, so I have no code I've tried with this)

EDIT:

I just did this:

```
var first_key = 0
var second_key = 2
var first_value = dict[first_key]!
var second_value = dict[second_key]!
dict[first_key] = second_value
dict[second_key] = first_value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a temporary variable to hold one of the values when you exchange them.

```
let tmp = dict[0]
dict[0] = dict[2]
dict[2] = tmp
```

Or you can use the global swap function for this (which does the same thing internally).

```
var dict = [
    0: "82",
    1: "12",
    2: "3",
    3: "42"
]

swap(&dict[0], &dict[2])
```

Answer (score 6):

When you have to swap variables, the simplest way is by using tuples.

If you want to swap `x` and `y`:

```
(x, y) = (y, x)
```

In your case:

```
(dict[0], dict[2]) = (dict[2], dict[0])
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote - if the solution doesn't work, I think it would be good to know

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this...why the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

You can do some thing like this to simply swap the values,

```
var dict = [
    0: "82",
    1: "12",
    2: "3",
    3: "42"
    // Etc.
]
if  let value = dict[key], let existingValue = dict[newKey] {
    dict[key] = existingValue
    dict[newKey] = value
}
```

Now, the value of dict is new, with the values you wanted. Or, you could also add category on Dictionary like this,

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func swap(key1: Key, key2: Key) {
        if  let value = self[key1], let existingValue = self[key2] {
            self[key1] = existingValue
            self[key2] = value
        }

    }
}


dict.swap(0, key2: 2)
print(dict)
```

Notice, you dont really need to pass a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
var random = ["LAX":"Los Angeles", "JFK":"New York"]


func flip <T, U>(_ dictionary: Dictionary<U, T>) -> Dictionary<T, U> {

 
    let arrayOfValues: [T] = Array(dictionary.values)
    let arrayOfKeys: [U] = Array(dictionary.keys)

    var newDictionary: [T: U] = [:]
    
    for i in 0...arrayOfValues.count-1 {
       
        newDictionary[arrayOfValues[i]] = arrayOfKeys[i]
        
    }
    
    return newDictionary
    
}

flip(random) // You will get ["Los Angeles": "LAX", "New York": "JFK"]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.